# Can you get polygon collider 2d shape from a sprite?

Tags: unity, sprites, meshcollider

When you create an object with polygon collider 2d from inspector, unity automatically generates polygon collider that approximately fits the sprite. My question is if there is a way to do that when creating an object from a script? While searching for a solution I found that each sprite has a sprite mesh which has vertices. I tried setting those as a path for my collider, but the result is a mess: their order appears to be messed up. My current code:

```
         Sprite spr; // I get that in other part of the code
         GameObject go = GameObject)Instantiate(prefab,gameObject.transform);
         go.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = spr;
         go.GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>().SetPath(0, spr.vertices);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AddComponent<PolygonCollider2D>()` to generate collider runtime.

```
void Start () 
{
    gameObject.AddComponent<PolygonCollider2D>(); //collider for itself
    obj2.AddComponent<PolygonCollider2D>(); //collider for other object
}
```

[image]

`SetPath()` is used to manipulate vertex runtime.